# What is the easiest way to run python scripts in a cloud server?

Tags: python, cloud, web-crawler, virtual, server

I have a web crawling python script that takes hours to complete, and is infeasible to run in its entirety on my local machine. Is there a convenient way to deploy this to a simple web server? The script basically downloads webpages into text files. How would this be best accomplished?
Thanks!

Comment: May be you're asking for [this](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/).

Answer (score 9):

Since you said that performance is a problem and you are doing web-scraping, first thing to try is a [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) framework - it is a very fast and easy to use web-scraping framework. [`scrapyd`](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tool would allow you to distribute the crawling - you can have multiple `scrapyd` services running on different servers and split the load between each. See:

- [Distributed crawls](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#distributed-crawls)
- [Running Scrapy on Amazon EC2](http://seminar.io/2013/03/26/running-scrapy-on-amazon-ec2/)

There is also a [`Scrapy Cloud`](http://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud) service out there:

> Scrapy Cloud bridges the highly efficient Scrapy development
>   environment with a robust, fully-featured production environment to
>   deploy and run your crawls. It's like a Heroku for Scrapy, although
>   other technologies will be supported in the near future. It runs on
>   top of the Scrapinghub platform, which means your project can scale on
>   demand, as needed.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to the solutions already given, I would suggest **Heroku**. You can not only deploy easily a website, but also scripts for bots to run.

Basic account is free and is pretty flexible.

[This blog entry](http://briancaffey.github.io/2016/04/05/twitter-bot-tutorial.html), [this one](https://bigishdata.com/2016/12/15/running-python-background-jobs-with-heroku/) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwWPunpypNA) contain practical examples of how to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple places where you can do that. Just google for "python in the cloud", you will come up with a few, for example https://www.pythonanywhere.com/.

In addition, there are also several cloud IDEs that essentially give you a small VM for free where you can develop your code in a web-based IDE and also run it in the VM, one example is http://www.c9.io.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- thanks for the mention! :-)   Let me also add that we have a number of customers using us for Scrapy.  This way of keeping the scripts running is quite popular: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/LongRunningTasks

Answer (score 3):

In 2021, Replit.com makes it very easy to write and run Python in the cloud.

Comment: I couldn't get my envs working in this :-/
Moving on!!

Answer (score -1):

If you have a google e-mail account you have an access to google drive and utilities. Choose for colaboratory (or find it in more... options first). This "CoLab" is essentially your python notebook on google drive with full access to your files on your drive, also with access to your GitHub. So, in addition to your local stuff you can edit your GitHub scripts as well.