# Running a python script on a server and saving data to the cloud

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, server, google-cloud-storage

I want to store data regarding loan rates for assets on an exchange. There are around 8 assets, this is an example of the [API call](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnLoanOrders&currency=BTC) i will be using to query the data for each asset.

I'm planning on running a script for each asset. Basically each script will be a while loop that continuously queries the API, if the data changes (a new loan is added or removed) the data from that call is saved (ie duplicates aren't saved) I will be saving the data as json files. (each one around 5Kb and around 5000 an hour)

I have estimated from various tests that I will need at max 250GB a year.

I have never done anything like before. I was was looking into [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/pricing/) a service which allows you to paste your script and let them do all the sever work. Although I would would like like to learn how to use AWS, as it would broaden my knowledge and be useful for future projects. And then then save the data to something, like dropbox?

Can anyone give recommendations from their experience ? this could be regarding my method of queering and saving the data, the server or where to actually store the data.

Ideally i would like to do it for a cheap as possible.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901882/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-run-python-scripts-in-a-cloud-server) for more information about server alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be using a AWS EC2 `t2.nano` ($5/month) or `t2.micro` ($9/month) instance in AWS for compute and using AWS S3 storage. With python and boto3, what you are trying to do is not difficult (you can code and test it in a day). But if you are not familiar with AWS ecosystem, there is some learning curve.

I checked the site you mentioned which takes care of coding, compute and storage. I have never used it but looks the cheapest.

If you want to learn about AWS, go with the first option. If time and cost are more important, go with the second option.