# What is the easiest way to schedule the execution of a Python file using cloud computing solutions?

Tags: python, cloud

I have a Python file that I'd like to run every day in the cloud. Now, I know, I know: AWS, Google Cloud, Azure, and countless other services are more than capable of doing this. But, honestly, I have no experience using any of those ecosystems, and using them for the first time can be pretty daunting.

It feels like I am largely missing something. I don't want some optimized, scalable, flexible, cost-effective, parallel-computed thing like these services tout, I just want to run a Python file every day.

What's the absolute simplest solution?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901882/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-run-python-scripts-in-a-cloud-server) that is very similar to mine, but it's from 2014, the answers seem to assume you already know a lot about cloud computing, and available technology has changed a lot since then. I'm hoping to get the 2024 answer to this question.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for off-site resources are specifically off-topic here. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: Question seems too broad. Which cloud? Which OS? `cron`, `systemd` tasks, Task Scheduler on Windows, or `google cloud scheduler <provider>`.